# How to connect to SQL Server CE database from ASP.NET Core Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, sql-server-ce

I have connected to my SQL Server Compact Edition database from an ASP.NET console application. I am using the same thing and libraries to connect to SQL Server CE database file in my ASP.NET Core Web API application, but I get an exception.

My code:

```
public  class ClienDetailRepository: IClientDetailRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    private static string DbFilePath = @"C:\Git\Forecaster\DB\THSTaxPro.sdf";
    private static string DbPassword = "*****";
    private static string DbMaxSize = "4090";

    public static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + DbFilePath + ";Password=" + DbPassword + ";Max Database Size=" + DbMaxSize + "";

    public ClienDetailRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        //_connectionString = ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

I am getting error on this line

```
  SqlCeConnection sqlconTHS = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
```

This is the error:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection' threw an exception

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Windows? I tested on Windows, and your problem did not occur, you can refer to my steps below.

Copy the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` file and the entire `amd64` folder from the `Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private directory` to the folder where the `.csproj` file created:
[image]

Install the [Windows compatibility pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/8.0.0-preview.2.23128.3), to make any required Windows specific .NET APIs available.

Add a file reference to the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` file in the root of your project, and your .csproj file should end up like this(I'm using .net6):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>ProjectName</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="6.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest" />
        <None Remove="amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll" />
        <None Remove="amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\README_ENU.txt" />
        <None Remove="amd64\sqlceca40.dll" />
        <None Remove="amd64\sqlcecompact40.dll" />
        <None Remove="amd64\sqlceer40EN.dll" />
        <None Remove="amd64\sqlceme40.dll" />
        <None Remove="amd64\sqlceqp40.dll" />
        <None Remove="amd64\sqlcese40.dll" />
        <None Remove="System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\README_ENU.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceca40.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlcecompact40.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceer40EN.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceme40.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlceqp40.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="amd64\sqlcese40.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1">
            <HintPath>System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

My Test Code:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=THSTaxPro.sdf";

//using SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
//engine.CreateDatabase();

using SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

using (SqlCeCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    //command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Blogs ( Id INT, Title NVARCHAR(256) )";

    //command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Blogs";

    SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    int Count = reader.FieldCount;
}
```

Of course, please make sure your connectionString is correct.

Test Result:

[image]

For more detail, you can refer to [this link](https://erikej.github.io/sqlce/2020/08/17/netcore-sql-compact.html).